# Google Smart Lock across multiple apps

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

I've been trying to get Google's Smart Lock to work between two apps that I have (unfortunately with different keystores), but not having any luck.

It's straightforward to save a password in Smart Lock for one app (**APP 1**) doing something like:

```
Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(email)
            .setPassword(password)
            .build();
Auth.CredentialsApi.save(mCredentialsApiClient, credential).setResultCallback(...
```

However, when I try to make a `CredentialRequest` in **APP 2** it's not able to read the same credentials saved from **APP 1**.
I've tried setting the `accountType` to the same identifier between them like:

```
Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(email)
            .setPassword(password)
            .setAccountType(ACCOUNT_TYPE)
            .build();
Auth.CredentialsApi.save(mCredentialsApiClient, credential).setResultCallback(...
...
CredentialRequest request = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
            .setAccountTypes(ACCOUNT_TYPE)
            .build();

Auth.CredentialsApi.request(mCredentialsApiClient, request).setResultCallback(...
```

But I get an exception stating you can't set both the `password` and `accountType` on the same credential (which matches what the documentation says).

Anyone tried something similar between two apps? 
I should note, I'm unable to tie my credentials from the apps up with my website sign in at the moment, so can't use the `Digital Asset Links` mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, the [digit asset linking](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites) is the only way to associate multiple apps with different package names and signing certificates for password retreival with Smart Lock.

If you can't support credentials from the website yet, then simply exclude the "web" target from the digital asset links file and credentials will only be shared between the apps (but you still have to host the file somewhere and include a link to this file in both app manifests).

Comment: Awesome thanks, I thought that might have been the case. Would I still need to publish via Play Store to test it works? Wasn't able to submit a beta build to check myself.
Or is there another way to force the apps to validate the digital asset linking file?

Comment: We're only able to process the linking for published Play Store apps, but you could publish to a private beta channel. Once published, it takes a few days for crawler to fetch the file and process it, sorry it's not faster :/

Comment: thanks! Submitted to my Play Store beta to check it out 

Comment: What's the package name? I'll check it for you.

Comment: Hi @StevenSoneff, what happens instead if the apps share the same signing certificate? Is using the digital asset linking still required for Smart Lock to use the same password for each app?

Comment: Yes, the linking needs to be explicit, it won't happen automatically even with the same cert used across apps.

Comment: Hi @Steven, Could you check our app for us? I actually created an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174695192 because the linkage still can't be built after our apps being published for 2 months.