# Google smart lock across multiple apps not work

Tags: android, google-contacts-api, google-smartlockpasswords

we are trying to enable automatic sign-in across apps and websites in our app according to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/associate-apps-and-sites)

Currently, we have done

1. Added the content related to our app to the Digital Assets Link JSON file
2. Added `asset_statemenets` to the manifest file
3. Added `asset_statements` string resource to the `strings.xml`
4. Published the app in google play store (100% rolled out)
5. Applied [Smart Lock for Passwords affiliation form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc3FCn8ccGpgXd1jtLBVRlNJ6EhWQK50hNO5jT_9nuqHI79pg/viewform) serval times, but haven't gotten any response. The last time we submitted it on 10/16

But the latest app still can't get credentials shared by other apps listed in Digital Assets Link JSON.
Is there a way to know the credential linking progress? currently, we don't know what's going on and can't know what issue we are having.

Comment: Found a similar question here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Comment: According to the comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119518/google-smart-lock-across-multiple-apps/43128620#43128620, Can anyone in Google help me to check the status of the credential linking by the package name?